# Writing into Oracle database via Java leading to ORA-00604 and ORA-01000

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I've got problems at trying to write data into my oracle table.
So, what I'm trying to do is to receive data from TMDB (tmdb.org) and write those into an Oracle table.

Here's my class where all the magic is happening:

```
public class Movies3 {

    public void execute_to_db() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, RuntimeException {

        final String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.XXX.XXX:XXX:XXX";
        final String user = "TEST2";
        final String password = "XXX";
        final String table = "TMDB_TEST";

        DatabaseConnect db = new DatabaseConnect();
        QueryCreateTable_Movies createtable = new QueryCreateTable_Movies();

        try {
            db.connect(user, password, url);

            ResultSet tablelike = db.processQuery(
                    "SELECT COUNT(table_name) " + "FROM all_tables " + "WHERE table_name = '" + table + "' ");

            PreparedStatement insert_ps = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + table + " "
                    + "(TMDB_ID, IMDB_ID, ORIGINAL_TITLE, TITLE_DE, BUDGET, REVENUE, RELEASE_DATE) "
                    + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            int tablelike_int = 0;
            while (tablelike.next())
                tablelike_int = tablelike.getInt(1);

            if (tablelike_int == 0)
                db.processInsert(createtable.create);

            else {


                TmdbMovies movies = new TmdbApi("XXX").getMovies();


                MovieDb latest_movie = movies.getLatestMovie();
                int tmdb_max_id = latest_movie.getId();

                try {



                    int id_exist = 0;


                    for (int i = 1; i < tmdb_max_id; i++) {

                        ResultSet id_existq = db
                                .processQuery("SELECT (tmdb_id) FROM " + table + " WHERE tmdb_id = " + i);
                        while (id_existq.next())
                            id_exist = id_existq.getInt(1);

                        if (id_exist == 0) {

                            try {

                                MovieDb movie_name_en = movies.getMovie(i, "en");
                                MovieDb movie_name_de = movies.getMovie(i, "de");
                                String original_title = movie_name_en.getOriginalTitle();
                                String title_de = movie_name_de.getTitle();
                                String imdb_id = movie_name_en.getImdbID();
                                int budget_en = (int) movie_name_en.getBudget();
                                int revenue_en = (int) movie_name_en.getRevenue();
                                String release_date_en = movie_name_en.getReleaseDate();

                                insert_ps.setInt(1, i);
                                insert_ps.setString(2, imdb_id);
                                insert_ps.setString(3, original_title);
                                insert_ps.setString(4, title_de);
                                insert_ps.setInt(5, budget_en);
                                insert_ps.setInt(6, revenue_en);
                                insert_ps.setString(7, release_date_en);

                                insert_ps.executeUpdate();

                                /** Start Output **/

                                double percent = (i * 100) / tmdb_max_id;

                                StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder(140);
                                int percent_int = (int) percent;
                                long total = (long) tmdb_max_id;
                                long current = (long) i;
                                string.append('\r').append(String.join("",
                                        Collections.nCopies(percent_int == 0 ? 2 : 2 - (int) (Math.log10(percent_int)),
                                                " ")))
                                        .append(String.format(" %d%% [", percent_int))
                                        .append(String.join("", Collections.nCopies((percent_int / 2), "=")))
                                        .append('>')
                                        .append(String.join("",
                                                Collections.nCopies((100 / 2) - (percent_int / 2), " ")))
                                        .append(']')
                                        .append(String.join("",
                                                Collections.nCopies(
                                                        (int) (Math.log10(total)) - (int) (Math.log10(current)), " ")))
                                        .append(String.format(" %d/%d | TMDB_ID: %d | Movie: %s", current, total, i,
                                                original_title));

                                System.out.flush();
                                System.out.print(string);

                                /** End Output **/

                                i++;

                                tmdb_max_id = latest_movie.getId();

                            } catch (RuntimeException e) {

                                continue;
                            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                                System.err.println(sqle + " SQL ERROR at movie with ID" + i);
                                throw sqle;
                            } finally {
                                id_existq.close();
                                insert_ps.close();
                                tablelike.close();
                            }

                        } else
                            i++;

                    }

                } catch (SQLException sqle2) {
                    throw sqle2;
                } catch (RuntimeException e2) {
                    throw e2;
                } finally {

                    insert_ps.close();
                    tablelike.close();
                }
            }

            db.disconnect();
        } catch (SQLException sqle_con) {
            throw sqle_con;

        }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException clnf) {
            throw clnf;

        } finally {


        }
    }

}
```

When executing, I receive ORA-00604 and ORA-01000.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: Fehler auf rekursiver SQL-Ebene 1
ORA-01000: Maximale Anzahl offener Cursor überschritten
ORA-00604: Fehler auf rekursiver SQL-Ebene 1
ORA-01000: Maximale Anzahl offener Cursor überschritten
ORA-01000: Maximale Anzahl offener Cursor überschritten

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:195)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:876)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1498)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:406)
    at database.DatabaseConnect.processQuery(DatabaseConnect.java:31)
    at tmdb_api_to_db.Movies3.execute_to_db(Movies3.java:75)
    at tmdb_api_to_db.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

I'm pretty sure, that the problem occurs because I got a fallacy with those try-catch-finally constructions - especially when closing my statements - but can't find my mistake and I simply feeling like a dog chasing its tail...

I'm using Eclipse Neon2 on Java 8 and Oracle 11g.
If there is further information needed, I'd be happy to provide.
Please consider that I'm not very experienced and thus be forgiving, if my question hurts any feelings... :)

Comment: *"If there is further information needed, I'd be happy to provide."* - Stack traces with full error messages.

Comment: @StephenC added error messages into question. That's what you asked for, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tranlated into English says

```
Maximum number of open cursors exceeded
```

The problem is that you are leaking cursors.  One place where this could happen is in the inner `for` loop.

When the body of

```
if (id_exist == 0) {
```

is not executed, the try / finally where you should be closing the `ResultSet` is never executed.  That will leak a cursor.  Eventually, Oracle won't let you open any more ...

I'm going to recommend that you read up on the "try with resources" constructed that has been supported by Java since Java 7.

It allows you to write resource cleanup code that is easier to read AND less error prone.

---

Also, if you find that you have a method where the majority of the code is indented 9 levels deep.  That should be a sign to you that you need to refactor it.  Seriously, you don't *need* to do all of that in a single monolithic method.  For a start, refactoring your code will make it easier for you (and everyone else) to understand.

Comment: thanks so far for your answer! I already tried to use the try-with-resourced statement. The problem I got now is, that everything that would make sense putting in is shown as an error e.g.: 'The resource type DatabaseConnect does not implement java.lang.AutoCloseable'. So, when looking for the method and putting in AutoCloseable, it still is shown as an error. I'll keep trying to get it to work. If I'm lost, I'll check back.

Comment: What exactly is the "database.DatabaseConnect" class?

Comment: I handle my database connection there.
see http://pastebin.com/Wbf3UE51

Comment: OK.  So the reason that try-with-resources did not work with your `DatabaseConnect` class was that it didn't implement `AutoCloseable`.  The second problem was probably that you didn't declare the `close()` method in that class.  That's a bad thing in any case, because without it your class cannot release the `DatabaseConect` object's connection.

Comment: Comment.  That `DatabaseConnect` is more of a hindrance than a help.  In addition to the missing `close()` it has a resource leak in `processInsert`.

Comment: Okay. As I only get it roughly: How do I implement `AutoCloseable` properly? And how is `close()` to be declared? So it's not enough to declare a `disconnect()` method and put the `close()` in it?

Comment: The javadoc for the `AutoCloseable` explains the signature for `close`, and what it is supposed to do.